# QGIS Connection PostGIS and shapefile?

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile

I'm working on QGIS with a database created in PostGIS and a shapefile. Inside the database, I have geometry type data about location of some points, instead on the shapefile there some selected areas.

With these 2 kind of data, I would like to know if there are some points inside or close to the shapefile area. For example: is there a point inside a selected area?

Can I select a part of the total area to see points also near to it?

Is there a query tool to use?

How can I connect these data created in different layers?

Comment: Two options: If you save the postGIS point locations as a shapefile, then you can use the "Points in Polygon" vector tool to count how many points in each polygon. Second, if you upload the polygon shapefile to PostGIS you can use several functions to find points within (ST_Contains()) or near (ST_DWithin()) each polygon.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily using the "Count Points in Polygon" algorithm in the processing toolbox. This doesn't require changing the original format of your data, and can work across both shapefiles and PostGIS databases. Here's some steps to do this:

1. Load both the shapefile area layer and the PostGIS point layer into QGIS
2. Open the processing toolbox by clicking "Processing" -> "Toolbox"
3. Enter "Count points in polygon" in the search box at the top, then double click the "Count points in polygon" result under Geoalgorithms->Vector->Statistics
4. Choose your shapefile area layer in the "Polygons" combo box, and the PostGIS point layer in the "Points" combo box.
5. Choose an output file for the result, and click "Run" to perform the analysis.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not concerned about specific counts a simple query option would be to use the [Spatial Query](https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_spatial_query.html) plugin.  Your dataset type may be in any combination of formats (shp to PostGIS...etc).

> The Spatial Query plugin allows to make a spatial query (select
>   features) in a target layer with reference to another layer. The
>   functionality is based on the GEOS library and depends on the selected
>   source feature layer.